# How to allow parameters on different lines in Dart?

Tags: formatting, format, lint, dart

When i set lineLength to 200, which I would like to keep to not be limited, dart formatter is changing this:

```
throw RequestException(
  message: responseData['message'],
  statusCode: responseData['status'],
  response: responseData['response']
);
```

to this:

```
throw RequestException(message: responseData['message'], statusCode: responseData['status'], response: responseData['response']);
```

How can I allow parameters on different lines? More generally, how can I force it to keep my multi-lines for any kind of statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try ending it with a `,`

Like this:

```
throw RequestException(
  message: responseData['message'],
  statusCode: responseData['status'],
  response: responseData['response'],  // <- here
);
```